# What is error of this query ? Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    l.LocationName, l.LocationPrefixCode, 
    sum(case lt.transid when 1 then lt.Points else 0 end) as TotalEarnpoints, 
    sum(case lt.transid when 2 then lt.points else 0 end) as TotalRedeempoints, 
    sum(case lt.transid when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NoOfBillsEarned, 
    sum(case lt.transid when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as NoOfBillsRedeemed
from 
    InvLoyaltyTransaction lt 
inner join
    dbo.Location l ON lt.LocationID = l.LocationID 
where 
    cast(DocumentDate as date) between convert(date, '" + fromDate + "', 103)  
                                   and convert(date, '" + toDate + "', 103) 
    and CardType in (select CardMasterID 
                     from CrmReportCondition) 
    and lt.LocationID != 1
group by
    l.LocationName, l.LocationPrefixCode 
order by 
    l.LocationName
```

Comment: is this plain SQL? you shouldn't have double quotes in your query.

Comment: Use `@` at the beginning of your sql query string. Then you can wrap lines without using `+` or `"`.

Comment: What condition are you checking in the CASE clause? The syntax is: CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <cmd> ELSE <cmd_alt> END. There is nothing between "CASE" and "WHEN".

Comment: This code is syntactically correct. You may get an error in any other piece of code. Double click the error in SSMS and it will position your cursor to the row ewhere the error occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
l.LocationName, l.LocationPrefixCode, 
sum(case when lt.transid=1 then lt.Points else 0 end) as TotalEarnpoints, 
sum(case when lt.transid=2 then lt.points else 0 end) as TotalRedeempoints, 
sum(case when lt.transid=1 then 1 else 0 end) as NoOfBillsEarned, 
sum(case when lt.transid=2 then 1 else 0 end) as NoOfBillsRedeemed
from 
    InvLoyaltyTransaction lt 
inner join
    dbo.Location l ON lt.LocationID = l.LocationID 
where 
    cast(DocumentDate as date) between convert(date, '" + fromDate + "', 103)  
                                   and convert(date, '" + toDate + "', 103) 
    and CardType in (select CardMasterID 
                     from CrmReportCondition) 
    and lt.LocationID != 1
group by
    l.LocationName, l.LocationPrefixCode 
order by 
    l.LocationName
```